# Why am I getting these React PropType errors when I have specified what they are erroring about?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, apollo, react-proptypes

I have an edit form component that is wired up with `Apollo Client` and `Redux-Form`, and I also have `prop-types` installed.

I am remembering some reading I have done over time that 3rd party libraries can sometimes throw these kind of messages if they are missing proptypes, or if some parent component of mine isn't using prop-types correctly.

I am having difficulty reasoning about it though because I don't know where to look or why.

Here is a screenshot of the errors, one from `Apollo`, and one from `Redux-Form`:

[image]
But,

I have prop types declared on this view:

```
PersonEdit.propTypes = {
  ... ✂
  client: PropTypes.shape(PropTypes.any),
  initialValues: PropTypes.shape(PropTypes.object),
}

PersonEdit.defaultProps = {
  ... ✂
  client: undefined,
  initialValues: undefined,
}
```

I also tried with `isRequired` included on them:

```
PersonEdit.propTypes = {
  ... ✂
  client: PropTypes.shape(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
  initialValues: PropTypes.shape(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
}
```

Can anyone help me understand the nature of these prop-type related errors?

I feel very strongly that I read about this before, and that it might involve some "parent" logic or something getting called before the view, but I am unclear how to figure it out.

I dont understand why it says `initialValues.isRequired` or `client.isRequired` when my code **doesn't specify them as required**.

Oh, and here is my export for this edit form, because I feel like there is a chance it is related:

```
export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, {
    onServerError,
    getPerson,
    onBackPress,
  }),
  // graphql(PERSON_EDIT_MUTATION),
  reduxForm({
    validate,
    form: 'PersonEdit',
    enableReinitialize: true,
  }),
)(withApollo(PersonEdit))
```

I just tried remixing the code and chopping various things out around the time `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount` run, and I commented everything out to trigger the `NotFoundPage` component instead of the edit form, and it is still generating the same errors.

The errors go away if I comment out the `propTypes` and `defaultProps` declarations, so it is somehow related to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is surely related with this code

```
PersonEdit.defaultProps = {
  ... ✂
  client: undefined,
  initialValues: undefined,
}
```

You are setting props to be objects and you are settings their value to undefined. Why do you do that?

Just set it to something like (or whatever that is not undefined)

```
PersonEdit.defaultProps = {
  ... ✂
  client: null,
  initialValues: null,
}
```

Also, why are you setting type checking like that? Why do you use any and object inside shape? You could just write it as this

```
PersonEdit.propTypes = {
  ... ✂
  client: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  initialValues: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I cannot use `PropTypes.any`, `PropTypes.object`, or `PropTypes.array` because they are forbidden by `eslint-config-airbnb`, because they are not descriptive enough. You can use them inside `PropTypes.shape()` or `PropTypes.arrayOf()`. I believe PropTypes.any is the same as putting nothing. Why even check types if anything is allowed?

Comment: I tried changing those defaults to `null` but it doesn't change it. I'm starting to think it is something to do with the way babel is transpiling.

Comment: But, thanks to your alert, I investigated putting a different constraint on it, and it worked to make the errors go away:   `client: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any),`
  `initialValues: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any),`

Comment: I know that airbnb lint is quite conservative, but I think you are just fooling the not descriptive rule and not complying to it. The rule is there to remind you to declare object properties so that you don't have undesired and not handled errors.